# Play two DRM-protected songs at the same time with different volumes

Tags: ios, swift, drm, mpmusicplayercontroller, apple-musickit

I'm attempting to create an effect with two different `MPMusicPlayerControllers` at different volumes. I'm able to create one `MPMusicPlayerController` and set the volume of that

```
let musicPlayerController = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer

let volumeController = MPVolumeView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
self.view.addSubview(volumeController)

// get the UISlider for the MPVolumeView
let volumeSlider = volumeController.volumeSlider
volumeSlider.value = 0.5

musicPlayerController.play()
```

Yet now that [`MPMusicPlayerController.volume` is deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller/1624567-volume), I can't seem to figure out a way to create two MPMusicPlayerControllers with different volumes... I'm looking for something like this

```
let musicPlayerController = MPMusicPlayerController()
musicPlayerController.volume = 0.5
//set the song
musicPlayerController.play()

let otherPlayerController = MPMusicPlayerController()
otherPlayerController = 0.5
//set the song
otherPlayerController.play()
```

I'm unable to use `AVAudioPlayer` because of the limitations it has with DRM protected files. Essentially I'm trying to play two DRM protected music files at different volume levels at the same time.

Is there any way to create (or have the same effect as) two different `MPMusicPlayerControllers` at different volumes in iOS 10 or 11 (something like playing two songs at different volumes on the same `MPMusicPlayerController`)? Hacky workarounds are welcome.

Comment: I think systemMusicPlayer is only a reference to a systemwide music player that is a singleton. Try appMusicPlayer and see if you get a different result.

let player01 = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer()
        let player02 = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer()

Comment: @solenoid Thanks for your response! I've tried doing that, but can't figure out how to change the volume of the two independently (I mentioned that later in the question, but probably should have included it in the title — I just updated the post)

Comment: Ahh volume - I have my doubts on that one. Out of curiosity, what music wont play in AVPlayer? In my app I only play local music and only songs with the old-style DRM wont load up.

Comment: @solenoid I'm fetching the songs downloaded from Apple Music into a playlist on the user's phone. when I use `MPMediaItem.assetURL`, I end up with a URL like *ipod-library://item/item.m4a?id= 3816532951739856891*. When I create a new `AVAudioPlayer` with that URL and call play(), I get no error, but no sound comes out of the device. When I use `MPItem.filepathURL`, I get nil.

Comment: Hmm, I remember something like that happening due to a not set up AVAudiosession... you have         do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error with audio session", error)
        }

I am not sure filepathURL ever returns anything i will test later if the above doesnt solve it

Comment: @solenoid I just tried that as well as `try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)` after it, creating an `AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: myMPMediaItem.assetURL!)`, and then calling `play()` on the new audio player, but the audio still does not play...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151324/discussion-between-solenoid-and-jojodmo).

Comment: @Jojodmo did you get solution ?

Comment: @ArpitBParekh Unfortunately, not as of now.

Comment: Is there any way I can play DRM tracks except MPMusicPlayer.? Thanks for response @Jojodmo

Comment: @ArpitBParekh As far as I’m aware, no. If you happen to stumble upon a solution, it would be greatly appreciated if you could post it here.

Comment: Hmm, Thanks. I will surely post if something positive.

Comment: I am trying with Pandora Player (https://github.com/ApplikeySolutions/PandoraPlayer) project shown  error running project, and and second I will try using AVAudioEngine, It showed exceptions while playing. I need to check.

Comment: @JojodmoI am getting nil URL for downloaded songs from apple music. Did you get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've contacted Apple and they confirmed that there is currently no way to do this. I filed a feature suggestion, so hopefully we'll be able to see this in the future.

My feature suggestion suggested using a global handler and a delegate, allowing for the app to make commands to the handler (something like `MPDRMMusicHandler.shared`), and then receive responses to those commands via a delegate `MPDRMMusicDelegate`, assigned to the music handler session `MPDRMMusicHandler`.

At no point would the app be able to access the unencrypted, raw music data, as the app would only be able to send requests for music to be played and to set characteristics of it. Then, the delegate functions would be called in a response to those commands — indicating if the commands succeeded or providing errors if they failed. The decryption of the DRM-protected music would all be handled by iOS, separate from the app (or, at least in a private library developers "can't" access).